# Why is there an asteroid scene at the beginning and at the end of Birdman?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, birdman

Why is there is an asteroid scene at the beginning and at the end of the movie *Birdman*?
Did that asteroid strike Riggan and give him the power to fly?

Answer (score 1):

I like to think this is a metaphor about Riggan's fall. Riggan is a part of a powerful and massive planet, but he left it (Planet Birdman) and he does not know to what he belongs.

While he falls, he is struggling and tries to hang on to anything around (friends, family). The bright light generated by an Asteroid could be his show, or his lost career).

He does not care about disappearing (he even wants to disappear as Birdman).

So for me it's just a movie summary, and it reminds us that an asteroid is not designed to fall, but to fly, until he meets an obstacle. And he is not crashing, which means to me: He is not falling, he is convinced he is, but he eventually will fly through space, without any bond.